# Parallel axis theorem proof in Kleppner and Kolenkow

Tags: rotational-dynamics, textbook-erratum

In page 249 of Kleppner and Kolenkow, An introduction of Classical Mechanics, for the proof of Parallel axis theorem, he writes the vector connecting the axis(z-axis) to mass element is :

$$ \rho_j= x_j \vec{i} + y_j \vec{k}$$

Now, if it is the perpendicular vector connecting the axis to a mass element then why is there $k$ component..?

**Reference picture:**

[image]

Comment: It is a typo (read the rest of the proof). It should have been $y_j \vec{j} $ instead of $y_j \vec{k} $.

Comment: Nice! post this as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @Buraian Do you feel you understand what the parallel axis theorem means/

Comment: What I understand: if you want the inertia about some axis, then you can find the inertia of an axis parallel to that and passing through the center of mass, and using this, find the inertia of the original axis in question

Answer (score 1):

From the comment by Omar Nagib,

It is a typo.

The correction : $y_i \vec{j}$  instead of  $yj\vec{k}$